# What is the logic to convert date and time fields to Time.Posix?

Tags: time, elm, epoch

I have a view that allows me to store day, month, year, hours and minute fields in my model.

I have to store the data in the Time.Posix type.

What is the logic for conversion? 
How do I transform the data from the input fields into epoch time?

As a side note, links to any good resources for posix time computation would be appreciated.

Comment: This question is way too broad I think. And the only non-trivial part of it is the conversion from day/month/year etc. to unix time, which should be done with a library. And library recommendations are really off-topic too. But [this](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/PanagiotisGeorgiadis/elm-datetime/latest/) seems like a good alternative. And [here](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/justinmimbs/time-extra/latest/Time-Extra)'s another one.

Comment: I suggest you go to https://package.elm-lang.org/ and type in "time". Have a go with one of the results and let us know if you have a more specific problem. (hint: you probably want https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/rtfeldman/elm-iso8601-date-strings/latest/)

Comment: Stack Overflow encourages specific questions where you have a problem with some code. For general recommendations and advice, consider https://discourse.elm-lang.org/